# How can I render more than multiple posts on template-parts with post formats

Tags: php, themes, get-posts

I am trying to make a Wordpress theme. In my theme, there are multiple post formats and all are rendered on the index.php
something like this website `www.theoutline.com`  It has a 1st section with single and as you scroll it has more than one post on other section and the same format goes on till the end of the page. Here I am confused about how to achieve this. Do I need to make another query for them or is there any other way.
Please let me know if there is any way to do this.

I am query posts like this.

```
<?php
        if(have_posts()): ?> 
            <div class="row">
            <?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_format());?>

            <?php endwhile;wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>

        <?php else: ?>


            <?php get_template_part('/template-parts/content', 'none');?>

        <?php endif
        ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to display all posts sorted by post format? (each "post-format" posts in own section?)

Comment: @anton yes, but I am not sure how to do that. please help me if you know how to do this.